# Mount volume from Jenkins Pipeline do not work

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I guys, I have a Jenkins Pipeline and at some point I have to run a docker run

```
sh 'ls $(pwd)'
sh 'docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/src cdrx/pyinstaller-windows ls /src'
```

The problem is that first line ls list correctly the current commit files, but for some reason I'm not able to mount this folder $(pwd) inside another container, in fact, the command ls /src is empty when did run from Jenkins agent, same command on host machine mount correctly the volume, I can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [$WORKSPACE environment variable](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-belowJenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables):

```
sh "docker run --rm -v '$WORKSPACE:/src' cdrx/pyinstaller-windows ls /src"
```

Answer (score 0):

quote it to make sure possible spaces in the pwd will be included and not treated as their own parameters...

```
sh 'docker run --rm -v "$(pwd):/src" cdrx/pyinstaller-windows ls /src'
```